# Bloomberg Professional Terminals

Tags: api, bloomberg

does anyone have a way to measure a **Bloomberg Terminals** general usage or excel API data usage.

This is the most informed way I have seen so far, anyone agree, disagree or have a better way.

https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/43713/how-to-monitor-the-bandwidth-consumption-of-individual-applications/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Agree if you're just trying to assess your own server bandwidth usage.

If you're referring to actual data consumption, it depends a little on what platform you're doing it on. You can't infer cost utilization from bandwidth usage, because some fields/data is significantly more expensive, so you may have a person using relatively less data, but incurring notably larger costs due to the entitlements they have requested or are using.

For the enterprise license, you can get a monthly usage summary in arrears for the utilization so it's pretty easy to track.

For B-Pipe you can run BPUR or DFRP on the terminal to run the usage stats, but you need to be permissioned.

On a straight terminal as you mentioned, this data is tracked by Bloomberg to ensure compliance with TOS so you can talk to your rep about getting some usage utilization. The limits team at Bloomberg though sees it binary, so you're either over or you're not.